# JSON character encoding vs utf8

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, utf-8

i have a proplem with JSON character encoding.when i call ajax and return encode utf8 string by `json_encode()` my key world is 'áo' but after encode it return '\u00c1o' but in javascript,jquery i want to compare that string with 'áo' how to do it(i don't want to compare \u00c1o with \u00c1o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is interpolated by JS for display and encoded for storage.  Thus, `'\u00c1o' == 'Áo'`.  Note that it does not equal `'áo'`, but this does work:

```
"áo" == "\u00c1o".toLowerCase()
```

Comment: I just reminded about the casing while I was afk, +1 for adding the missing bit first. `=]`

Answer (score 4):

An unicode escape sequence is no different than an UTF-8 character (provided your document and JS are served with UTF-8 encoding).

```
>>> '\u00c1o' === 'Áo'
<<< true
```

Note: Strings with different casing are considered different though. You may want to call `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` on both strings for case-insensitive comparison:

```
>>> '\u00c1o'.toLowerCase() === 'áo'.toLowerCase()
<<< true
```